# Wix doesn't remove previous version of burn exe during major upgrade

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.8, major-upgrade

I have created a wix exe using burn bootstrapper. When I try to do a major upgrade on it, the new version gets installed. The features missing in the new upgrade are also removed from the existing folder structure. But in "Add or Remove Programs" I can still find both the installations. I have incremented the version from 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.1.0 in Bootstrapper project's Bundle.wxs file. I have also incremented the version in Setup project's Product element from 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.1.0. I didn't change the upgrade code in either of these files. I also created new GUID for Product ID in Setup project's Product.wxs. What am I doing wrong here? Why is the previous version still there in Add or Remove Programs? Please advice.

Below is the Bootstrapper project's Bundle.wxs.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Bundle Name="Kube Installer" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Zone24x7" UpgradeCode="DA4CFB28-4441-43BE-9E8E-0E3C92206324">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost" >
      <Payload SourceFile="..\CustomBA\BootstrapperCore.config"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="..\CustomBA\bin\Release\CustomBA.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="..\CustomBA\bin\Release\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WPF4.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value=""/>
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value=""/>
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\KubeInstaller\bin\Release\KubeInstaller.msi" Id="KubeInstallationPackageId" Cache="yes" Visible="no"/>
    </Chain>

  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Below is the Setup project's Product.wxs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <Product Id="70F65E5D-F307-4155-8847-9E5A66024DE7" Name="Installer" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Zone24x7" UpgradeCode="E90569B5-372E-45BB-B101-58E0B75AB5C7">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64"/>

    <Property Id="JAVA_CURRENT_VERSION64">
      <RegistrySearch Id="JRE_CURRENT_VERSION_REGSEARCH64" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" Name="CurrentVersion" Type="raw" Win64="yes" />
    </Property>

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Installer" Level="1" >
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="NewFilesGroup2"/>
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="InstallDir" Name="Installer">
            <Directory Id="MyProgramDir2" Name="KKSDKService" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>


    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="MyProgramDir2" />
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="NewFilesGroup2">
            <Component Id="cmpB40D9BC07A10F4C7CA1D590EA22BC096" Directory="MyProgramDir2" Guid="6CEF1581-D3B4-43EC-A561-8E35CFD9AB67">
                <File Id="filCD18463F625BD1E6DABFF218E37514D9" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.MyDir2)\BarcodeScannerPlugin.jar" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpCEA7123B4B5BD564DC3955797750BDBD" Directory="MyProgramDir2" Guid="0828F282-7F66-4550-9D8B-B9DD914F50BA">
                <File Id="fil1C3696A75F0BD878925FCA64111719CE" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.MyDir2)\KKSDK.jar" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp754951538EA86C396458E93F7C5EE8D8" Directory="MyProgramDir2" Guid="83532EF6-0AE6-4B9C-824E-7309E4E97BFA">
                <File Id="fil9EEABE714F6AF741BE3D5AA5B5209994" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.MyDir2)\SDKTestPlugin.jar" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp89BABCFC5524994A65C4664EA4FACE6C" Directory="MyProgramDir2" Guid="3C7A05CE-F786-4E23-80B4-2FCB9ABB314C">
                <File Id="fil65C3299403B5E2113A60782D09D56C54" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.MyDir2)\ProfileManagerPlugin.jar" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpCB38C422B08F1CA1B1E85B1EA87CC1E6" Directory="MyProgramDir2" Guid="66766CBB-A4CD-46C9-94F5-79410A8981C2">
                <File Id="filC9B025CB143BD34F87C0041C5D550955" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.MyDir2)\RFIDScannerPlugin.jar" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp0F9E9EA430641A0340428B2A9E45E672" Directory="MyProgramDir2" Guid="203631E3-581B-49C4-8D38-2B2D1CB9DDCD">
                <File Id="filCA701380AEB33971329784A6C3186684" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.MyDir2)\WebSocketServerPlugin.jar" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

Below is the class which handles the installer related actions.

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        //constructor
        public MainViewModel(BootstrapperApplication bootstrapper)
        {

            this.IsThinking = false;

            this.Bootstrapper = bootstrapper;
            this.Bootstrapper.ApplyComplete += this.OnApplyComplete;
            this.Bootstrapper.DetectPackageComplete += this.OnDetectPackageComplete;
            this.Bootstrapper.PlanComplete += this.OnPlanComplete;

            this.Bootstrapper.CacheAcquireProgress += (sender, args) =>
            {
                this.cacheProgress = args.OverallPercentage;
                this.Progress = (this.cacheProgress + this.executeProgress) / 2;
            };
            this.Bootstrapper.ExecuteProgress += (sender, args) =>
            {
                this.executeProgress = args.OverallPercentage;
                this.Progress = (this.cacheProgress + this.executeProgress) / 2;
            };
        }

        #region Properties

        private bool installEnabled;
        public bool InstallEnabled
        {
            get { return installEnabled; }
            set
            {
                installEnabled = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("InstallEnabled");
            }
        }

        private bool uninstallEnabled;
        public bool UninstallEnabled
        {
            get { return uninstallEnabled; }
            set
            {
                uninstallEnabled = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("UninstallEnabled");
            }
        }

        private bool isThinking;
        public bool IsThinking
        {
            get { return isThinking; }
            set
            {
                isThinking = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsThinking");
            }
        }

        private int progress;
        public int Progress
        {
            get { return progress; }
            set
            {
                this.progress = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Progress");
            }
        }

        private int cacheProgress;
        private int executeProgress;

        public BootstrapperApplication Bootstrapper { get; private set; }

        #endregion //Properties

        #region Methods

        public void InstallExecute()
        {
            IsThinking = true;
            Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Install);
        }

        public void UninstallExecute()
        {
            IsThinking = true;
            Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall);
        }

        public void ExitExecute()
        {
            CustomBA.BootstrapperDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method that gets invoked when the Bootstrapper ApplyComplete event is fired.
        /// This is called after a bundle installation has completed. Make sure we updated the view.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnApplyComplete(object sender, ApplyCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            IsThinking = false;
            InstallEnabled = false;
            UninstallEnabled = false;
            this.Progress = 100;
            ExitExecute();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method that gets invoked when the Bootstrapper DetectPackageComplete event is fired.
        /// Checks the PackageId and sets the installation scenario. The PackageId is the ID
        /// specified in one of the package elements (msipackage, exepackage, msppackage,
        /// msupackage) in the WiX bundle.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnDetectPackageComplete(object sender, DetectPackageCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PackageId == "KubeInstallationPackageId")
            {
                if (e.State == PackageState.Absent)
                    InstallEnabled = true;

                else if (e.State == PackageState.Present)
                    UninstallEnabled = true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method that gets invoked when the Bootstrapper PlanComplete event is fired.
        /// If the planning was successful, it instructs the Bootstrapper Engine to 
        /// install the packages.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnPlanComplete(object sender, PlanCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Status >= 0)
                Bootstrapper.Engine.Apply(System.IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        #endregion //Methods

        #region RelayCommands

        private RelayCommand installCommand;
        public RelayCommand InstallCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (installCommand == null)
                    installCommand = new RelayCommand(() => InstallExecute(), () => InstallEnabled == true);

                return installCommand;
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand uninstallCommand;
        public RelayCommand UninstallCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (uninstallCommand == null)
                    uninstallCommand = new RelayCommand(() => UninstallExecute(), () => UninstallEnabled == true);

                return uninstallCommand;
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand exitCommand;
        public RelayCommand ExitCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (exitCommand == null)
                    exitCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExitExecute());

                return exitCommand;
            }
        }

        #endregion //RelayCommands
    }
```

Log File 1 :

```
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:18]i001: Burn v3.10.2.2516, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{71ae2d4e-5c00-442b-9ea1-00cec549800d}\KubePlatformSetup.exe
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:18]i003: This bundle is being run by a related bundle as type 'Upgrade'.
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:18]i009: Command Line: '-uninstall -quiet -burn.related.upgrade -burn.ancestors={f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c} -burn.embedded BurnPipe.{22EB703C-0051-46E7-8B68-BA209900F6F7} {B0B02376-A988-437A-92A4-6116CFBC5526} 13952'
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:18]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\KubePlatformSetup_20160422164918.log'
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:18]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Zone24x7'
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:18]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:18]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[0980:37B4][2016-04-22T16:49:18]i000: Launching custom TestBA UX
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i102: Detected related bundle: {f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.1.0, operation: None
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i103: Detected related package: {8C442A83-F559-488C-8CC4-21B1626F4B8E}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.1.0, language: 0 operation: Downgrade
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i103: Detected related package: {8201DD23-40A5-418B-B016-4D29BE6F010B}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.1.0, language: 0 operation: Downgrade
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i101: Detected package: KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId, state: Obsolete, cached: Complete
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i101: Detected package: MosquittoInstallerId, state: Obsolete, cached: Complete
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 3
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 1
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleLastUsedSource = G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\KubePlatformSetup_20160422164918.log
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Zone24x7
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = KubePlatformSetup
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\KubePlatformSetup.exe
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {71ae2d4e-5c00-442b-9ea1-00cec549800d}
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 1.0.0.0
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

Log File 2:

```
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:38]i001: Burn v3.10.2.2516, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{E6470133-8EFE-49DE-8561-A335091D3464}\.cr\KubePlatformSetup.exe
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:38]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\KubePlatformSetup.exe'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\KubePlatformSetup.exe'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\KubePlatformSetup_20160422164838.log'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'KubePlatformSetup'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:38]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Zone24x7'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:38]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:38]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[3204:3A5C][2016-04-22T16:48:38]i000: Launching custom TestBA UX
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:39]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:39]i102: Detected related bundle: {71ae2d4e-5c00-442b-9ea1-00cec549800d}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: MajorUpgrade
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:39]i103: Detected related package: {398C5992-4E70-4844-8063-48639892BACF}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:39]i103: Detected related package: {392D3E7F-6FCB-4EFD-A40F-B2F7C2CB6D44}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:39]i101: Detected package: KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId, state: Absent, cached: None
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:39]i101: Detected package: MosquittoInstallerId, state: Absent, cached: None
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:39]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i200: Plan begin, 2 packages, action: Install
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\KubePlatformSetup_20160422164838_000_KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId_rollback.log'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\KubePlatformSetup_20160422164838_000_KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId.log'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_MosquittoInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\KubePlatformSetup_20160422164838_001_MosquittoInstallerId_rollback.log'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_MosquittoInstallerId' to value 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\KubePlatformSetup_20160422164838_001_MosquittoInstallerId.log'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i201: Planned package: KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i201: Planned package: MosquittoInstallerId, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i207: Planned related bundle: {71ae2d4e-5c00-442b-9ea1-00cec549800d}, type: Upgrade, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, dependency: None
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i300: Apply begin
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i361: Created a system restore point.
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{89CCD5C8-EB48-4FB3-8FB5-32FC9EEAB83F}\.be\KubePlatformSetup.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c}\KubePlatformSetup.exe'
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c}, version: 1.0.1.0
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[3204:2B40][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i336: Acquiring container: WixAttachedContainer, copy from: G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\KubePlatformSetup.exe
[3204:2B40][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\'
[3680:350C][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i305: Verified acquired payload: KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8C442A83-F559-488C-8CC4-21B1626F4B8E}v1.0.1.0\KubeUpdaterServiceInstaller.msi.
[3680:350C][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i305: Verified acquired payload: cabDF68CF429512A78026D040F0FB13A50B at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cabDF68CF429512A78026D040F0FB13A50B, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8C442A83-F559-488C-8CC4-21B1626F4B8E}v1.0.1.0\cab1.cab.
[3680:350C][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i305: Verified acquired payload: MosquittoInstallerId at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\MosquittoInstallerId, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8201DD23-40A5-418B-B016-4D29BE6F010B}v1.0.1.0\MosquittoInstaller.msi.
[3680:350C][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab657E45B8C9A7EF24C9A74563C2FA6EB3 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab657E45B8C9A7EF24C9A74563C2FA6EB3, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8201DD23-40A5-418B-B016-4D29BE6F010B}v1.0.1.0\cab1.cab.
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {8C442A83-F559-488C-8CC4-21B1626F4B8E}, version: 1.0.1.0, package: KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:48:40]i301: Applying execute package: KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8C442A83-F559-488C-8CC4-21B1626F4B8E}v1.0.1.0\KubeUpdaterServiceInstaller.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" INSTALLLOCATION="G:\"'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:49:17]i319: Applied execute package: KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId, result: 0x0, restart: None
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:49:17]i325: Registering dependency: {f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c} on package provider: {8C442A83-F559-488C-8CC4-21B1626F4B8E}, package: KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:49:17]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {8201DD23-40A5-418B-B016-4D29BE6F010B}, version: 1.0.1.0, package: MosquittoInstallerId
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:49:17]i301: Applying execute package: MosquittoInstallerId, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8201DD23-40A5-418B-B016-4D29BE6F010B}v1.0.1.0\MosquittoInstaller.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" INSTALLLOCATION="G:\"'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:49:18]i319: Applied execute package: MosquittoInstallerId, result: 0x0, restart: None
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:49:18]i325: Registering dependency: {f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c} on package provider: {8201DD23-40A5-418B-B016-4D29BE6F010B}, package: MosquittoInstallerId
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:49:18]i301: Applying execute package: {71ae2d4e-5c00-442b-9ea1-00cec549800d}, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{71ae2d4e-5c00-442b-9ea1-00cec549800d}\KubePlatformSetup.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{71ae2d4e-5c00-442b-9ea1-00cec549800d}\KubePlatformSetup.exe" -uninstall -quiet -burn.related.upgrade -burn.ancestors={f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c}'
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i319: Applied execute package: {71ae2d4e-5c00-442b-9ea1-00cec549800d}, result: 0x0, restart: None
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[3680:38D0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleLastUsedSource = G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\KubePlatformSetup_20160422164838.log
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\KubePlatformSetup_20160422164838_000_KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId.log
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_MosquittoInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\KubePlatformSetup_20160422164838_001_MosquittoInstallerId.log
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Zone24x7
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = KubePlatformSetup
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\KubePlatformSetup.exe
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c}
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\KubePlatformSetup_20160422164838_000_KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId_rollback.log
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_MosquittoInstallerId = C:\Users\MACILA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\KubePlatformSetup_20160422164838_001_MosquittoInstallerId_rollback.log
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessFolder = G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessPath = G:\Projects\Kube2\kube-installer\KubePlatformSetup\KubePlatformSetup\bin\Release\KubePlatformSetup.exe
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 1.0.1.0
[3204:32B0][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

Comment: I see you are using a CustomBA.dll. Can you post the Planning portion of the bundle log from when you upgrade? I'm guessing your bootstrapper application is overriding the engine's plan for the related bundle from Absent to None or Present. The engine uses the interface method "OnPlanRelatedBundle(bundleID, *requestedstate)" and if you are setting the requested state to PRESENT or NONE then you'll leave the old bundle installed after the upgrade.

Comment: I have edited the question with the class that you requested :) Anything weird in there?

Comment: I'll have to take a look at the c# BA code tomorrow since the one I used is all in c++. The BA code should be useful but I want most to see the log from %temp% of an upgrade. You *should* see in the detect phase "Detected related bundle {GUID} ... Relation:MajorUpgrade" or something similar and in the planning portion of the log you should see Planning Related bundle and the state plan should be for it to be Absent and get uninstalled.

Comment: Hey there is an improvement. Major upgrade seems to work fine when I increment the version in Bootstrapper's Bundle.wxs and not in Setup project's Product.wxs. When I increment both, the previous version remains. But I dont understand as to why I shouldn't increment the version in product.wxs. That is where i'm making the changes.

Comment: The default behaviour of the wix burn bundle is to do nothing with the old bundle if the versions are the same. When making an bundle for upgrades  you must always upgrade the version. My bundle's version is tied to our build system's build number so we use Major.Minor.Build.Revision format where Major.Minor are the product version, build is the build # from the build system and the Revision is the codebase revision from svn. I'll try to add an answer with some more specific information on some workarounds later today.

Comment: I got that part. But I'm having an exe. Within that exe, I have a msi. So when I update contents of the msi, I updated the version of the msi and the version of the exe. This resulted in two exes(Previous one not getting uninstalled). But when I keep the version of the msi as it is (though I have updated the contents of the msi) and update only the versio of the exe, it works fine. This is the actual scenario for which I need explanation :)

Comment: Really need the runtime logs of the installs to have any chance of figuring out what is going wrong during the upgrade. The bootstrapper should always have a newer version to upgrade an older installed bootstrapper.

Comment: I've added the log files. Please note that this happens, when I increment the exe version as well as the msi version. It works fine when I leave the MSI version as it is and increment the exe version. Which doesn't make any sense. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Awesome these are pretty useful logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution atlast. I had to hook onto the DetectComplete method and call the plan method on the Engine. Below is how I did it.

```
void DetectComplete(object sender, DetectCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        Bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose,"fired! but does that give you any clue?! idiot!");
        if (LaunchAction.Uninstall == Bootstrapper.Command.Action)
        {
            Bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Invoking automatic plan for uninstall");
            Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: more info in here https://frozencloud.wordpress.com/2016/05/06/burn-bootstrapper-installer-major-upgrade-doesnt-uninstall-previous-version/

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot in my case. They also do the same thing in the WiX Toolset installer.

Answer (score 3):

From the logs I'm seeing a few things.

In regards to the Upgrade, it looks like it's properly detecting all the packages and planning them correctly.

The two installer packages are being installed as a major upgrade and the related bundle (the one that is being upgrade) is being detected and run to uninstall it as well.

The issues all seem to be coming from your uninstall of the previous bundle.

The log you labeled as "Log File 1" is actually the log from when your upgrade re-ran the currently installed bootstrapper to remove it. The problem as I see it is right here:

```
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i102: Detected related bundle: {f57e276b-2b99-4f55-9566-88f47c0a065c}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.1.0, operation: None
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i103: Detected related package: {8C442A83-F559-488C-8CC4-21B1626F4B8E}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.1.0, language: 0 operation: Downgrade
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i103: Detected related package: {8201DD23-40A5-418B-B016-4D29BE6F010B}, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.1.0, language: 0 operation: Downgrade
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i101: Detected package: KubeUpdaterServiceInstallerId, state: Obsolete, cached: Complete
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i101: Detected package: MosquittoInstallerId, state: Obsolete, cached: Complete
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:49:19]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0980:3888][2016-04-22T16:51:43]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
```

The desired process for all burn bootstrappers is to do Detect phase, Plan phase, Apply phase.

For some reason your uninstall when being run by a related bundle is just stopping after the detect phase.

I also suspect your machine may be in a weird state right now. I think you have several installed, but hidden in the add remove programs list, installs for KubeUpdaterServiceInstaller and MosquittoInstaller.

The first thing I would do is **stop** installing anything on your build/development machine. When authoring installers you *will* make mistakes and cause machines to get in weird states with regards to knowing what it has installed and doesn't have installed on it. I would suggest using a virtual environment for all your installer testing. When you mess something up you can easily revert to a clean state and start testing again. If you are using a virtual environment then just ignore this paragraph you're doing it right but make sure you clean everything before testing changes and testing the upgrade.

In your MSI wix I would suggest you use a "*" as the Product Id so you don't have to change it every build.

```
<Product Id="*" Name="Installer" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Zone24x7" UpgradeCode="E90569B5-372E-45BB-B101-58E0B75AB5C7">
```

and in your major upgrade element add AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes"

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" />
```

So you don't have to update the version every time you want to test an upgrade just rebuild the msi installer.

For reference, here are my Bootstrapper upgrade logs for the bootstrapper application and the logs for when it removes the old install. Notice some differences

[The Upgrade Install](http://pastebin.com/XzDPxSQP)

[When it re-runs the old installation to remove it](http://pastebin.com/rs640Akn)

The upgrade log looks basically the same as yours which is good but the re-run to uninstall log has some differences. I'm not totally sure without basically seeing your whole codebase (and I don't have the time or will to do that) how to fix these issues but hopefully something in this answer will help you out.

Comment: I tried in a fresh VM. Its stops with detect phase in that machine as well. Any ideas? im clueless :(

Comment: Try using Product Id="*" in your msi installers. I don't think you want the bootstrapper to be detecting the installs as "Obsolete" or "Operation: Downgrade".

Comment: well tried that too :( do you see any issues with the BA code here? All phases have been correctly addressed right?

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly wrong with the BA code unfortunately. One thing you can try is to add dummy interface methods for the IBootstrapperApplication in your implementation just so that you can put breakpoints everywhere and step through your code as it runs. You'll probably need to add System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); to Run() so that you can connect your debugger to it.

Comment: Thanks mate, I found the solution :) Really appreciate all your help